# filename..extension // Paperclip reprocess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip

Some kind of problem I can't resolve…

In some app, a method called on :before_create was prefixing the file's extension with a double-dot (ex. /images/13402/medium/hey-1..jpg)

The problem is fixed for the new ones, but nothing occurs when I apply a reprocess! on the old ones; and I'd like to know if anyone could help about it

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Comment: seems to be related to no fingerprint column (though this is a few years later) since the path is :style.:fingerprint.:content_type_extension so nil fingerprint gives style..extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reprocess / refresh only takes your original image and recreates the defined styles in your model class. So if your original image contains a file path with double dots in it, these are also applied to the generated styles. You have to clean up your original files and the stored file paths in your model records.

The only way **I** know would be to write a little script to modify this. Basically

```
foreach image
  strip out double dots from original file name
  rename file
  store new file path in model record
end
```

And then `rake paperclip:refresh`